# Extend Richfaces components - for example customize Datatable component for specific implementation

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces, custom-component

How to extend the functionality of Richfaces components for example Data table with custom header and sorting techniques. i have seen extended data table but did not get much information from it. Please point me to an example if at it is available.

Thanks

Soma

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can extend a JSF component with the regular java extension (`extends`). You will have to extend a number of classes, depending on the exact component:

- `UIComponentName`/`HtmlComponentName`
- `HtmlComponentNameRenderer`
- `ComponentNameTag`

and you might need to register the renderer in `faces-config.xml`.

You can take a look at [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/213094/JSF/java/Extending-JSF-Components), or google for "Extend JSF component" or "Create custom JSF component".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am specifically looking for richfaces custom component. I believe i have to create a JSPX file and some java scripts also for my functionality. i think they have CDK(component development kit). I am trying to understand it in detail. It is good if there are any examples.

Comment: @SomaSekhar A guy at my company extended the rich:calendar control doing what Bozho mentioned.  Have you had any luck so far?

Comment: Bozho's technique works for Richfaces 3.x.  Not 4.x, from what I can tell.